# What is the different between an Analytic Platform and Business Intelligence?

Tags: analytics, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, data-management

Business Intelligence is defined by Gartner as follows:

> **Business intelligence** (BI) platforms enable enterprises to build BI
>   applications by providing capabilities in three categories: analysis,
>   such as online analytical processing (OLAP); information delivery,
>   such as reports and dashboards; and platform integration, such as BI
>   metadata management and a development environment. (Gartner IT)

While BI supports the company in decision making, Data Warehouse helps with the purely technical supply of the data.

> A **data warehouse** is a storage architecture designed to hold data
>   extracted from transaction systems, operational data stores and
>   external sources. The warehouse then combines that data in an
>   aggregate, summary form suitable for enterprise-wide data analysis and
>   reporting for predefined business needs. (Gartner IT)

But what is exactly the different between an Analytic Platform and Business Intelligence?
Is an Analytic Platform called the entirety of Data Warehouse and Business Intelligence?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an analogy like:

- Business intelligence its the destination,its the objective
- The analytic platform is the ship that helps you get there
- The data warehouse is the fuel that feeds the ship and lets it take you to your destination.

Sometimes they are used as sinonyms ,and sometimes they appear as different thing, in the end its depends very much on the author, but sure they are related. The analytic plattform is not the same as a data warehouse, but the data warehouse is a substantial part of the analytic platform(for example the analytic platform could be a data warehouse + a data visualization tool, or a data warehouse, and semantic layer and a data exploration tool, etc etc)